# Perturbation lemma in probability

Tags: probability

The problem looks like this: ("=>" means weak convergence)

X_n => X iff for all f that is bounded and has continuous derivatives of all orders, Ef(X_n) -> Ef(X).

It is given as hint that we could use Perturbation lemma, i.e., X_n + cY => X + cY for all c>0 implies X_n => X.

Any idea on how the hint could be applied to solve the problem?

Thanks!